# Taplinx: InvalidResponseLengthException: readData on desfire EV1 card

Tags: mifare

When reading data from a DESFire EVO1 card (AES encryption) I get a InvalidResponseLengthException. I'm using the taplinx library version 1.5

**My code looks as follows:**

```
private void cardLogic(final Intent intent){

    CardType cardType = m_libInstance.getCardType(intent);

    Log.v(logTag, cardType.getTagName());

    IDESFireEV1 objDESFireEV1 = DESFireFactory.getInstance().getDESFire(m_libInstance.getCustomModules());



    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(AUTHENTICATION_KEY, "AES");

    KeyData kd = new KeyData();

    kd.setKey(key);

    try {

        objDESFireEV1.getReader().connect();

        objDESFireEV1.getReader().setTimeout(2000);

        objDESFireEV1.selectApplication(APP_ID);

        Log.v(logTag, objDESFireEV1.getAuthStatus());

        objDESFireEV1.authenticate(1, IDESFireEV1.AuthType.AES,KeyType.AES128 , kd);

        Log.v(logTag, objDESFireEV1.getAuthStatus());

        byte[] data = objDESFireEV1.readData(1, 0, 3);

        Log.v(logTag, data.toString());

    } catch(Throwable t) {

        Log.e(logTag, t.getMessage(), t);

    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
2018-11-22 10:19:13.874 20228-20228/eu.mobitrace.mifaredesfiretest2 E/app-logger: on New intent
2018-11-22 10:19:13.977 20228-20228/eu.mobitrace.mifaredesfiretest2 V/app-logger: DESFire EV1
2018-11-22 10:19:13.993 20228-20228/eu.mobitrace.mifaredesfiretest2 V/app-logger: Not Authenticated
2018-11-22 10:19:14.035 20228-20228/eu.mobitrace.mifaredesfiretest2 V/app-logger: AES
2018-11-22 10:19:14.045 20228-20228/eu.mobitrace.mifaredesfiretest2 E/app-logger: Authentication Error

com.nxp.nfclib.exceptions.InvalidResponseLengthException: Authentication Error

    at com.nxp.nfclib.desfire.ʻ.ˋ(:4559)

    at com.nxp.nfclib.desfire.ʻ.ˋ(:4600)

    at com.nxp.nfclib.desfire.ʿ.ˊ(:182)

    at com.nxp.nfclib.desfire.ʻ.getFileSettings(:2043)

    at com.nxp.nfclib.desfire.ʻ.ˏ(:2494)

    at com.nxp.nfclib.desfire.ʻ.readData(:2531)

    at eu.mobitrace.mifaredesfiretest2.MainActivity.cardLogic(MainActivity.java:101)
```

**Information I got from the maker of the card:**

- Application Id: This looks to work fine, when I enter a other ID I get a exception saying the app is not found
- Authentication Key: This also looks to work fine, It doesn't throw an exception when using this key. When I use a other one (zeros or reversed) it throws a exception right here
- Key Rights for this key: read(1)
- File-Id: 1
- Read offset: 0 bytes
- Read length: 3 bytes

**What I've tried:**

- Using the ISO command set: this was a total failure
- Playing around with the integers in the read command to check if there was a error made in creating this (starting counting from 0/1)

**Question**
What is going wrong here? Is it some kind of authentication problem or am I using the lib wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

byte[] data = objDESFireEV1.readData(1, 0, 3);

Changed to:

byte[] data = objDESFireEV1.readData(1, 0, 3, IDESFireEV1.CommunicationType.Plain,3);

Is it OK?

Comment: Hi! if you format your code it'll be easier for everyone to read it!

Comment: I have the same issue. `desfireEV2.readData()` does not work when the file is enciphered.